# A fairly Simple Script, but cannot see what is wrong here

Tags: powershell

I have written a fairly simple script, to simply retrieve users via the UserPrinsipalName. It fails with the following error:

> ```
> Get-AdUser : Property: 'UserPrincipalName' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
> At C:\Temp\changeUPN.ps1:8 char:16
> + ... serObject = Get-AdUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $Obj.UserPrinci ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
> ```

```
$Csv = Read-Host "Enter Path to the Csv file"
$sps = Import-csv -Path $Csv
Foreach ($Obj in $Sps) {
    Write-Host "Splitting UPN $($Obj.UserPrincipalName) to retreive domain information" -ForegroundColor Green
    $Domain = ($Obj.UserPrincipalName -split "@")[1]
    Write-Host "$($Obj.UserPrincipalName) is located in $($Domain)" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "Getting AD Object" -ForegroundColor Green
    $UserObject = Get-AdUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq "$Obj.UserPrincipalName"} -Server $Domain
    If ($UserObject) {
        Write-Host "UserObject $($UserObject.DistinguishedName) Retrieved" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Changing UPN" -ForegroundColor Green
        $NewUpn = $Obj.UserPrincipalName -Replace ("$Domain", "Contoso.com")
        Write-Host "New UserPrincipalName = $($NewUpn)" -ForegroundColor Green
        $UserObject | Set-AdUser -UserPrincipalName $NewUpn
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "Could not retrieve $($Obj.UserPrincipalName) from $($Domain)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `"` around `$obj.UserPrincipalName`, alternatively try: `-Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($obj.UserPrincipalName)'"`

Comment: Thx, it indeed resolved the issue. I often find myself struggling with these filters, as i feel they tend to differ within the different technology teams. Somethimes you need to use double quotes, single quotes, brackets, and somethimes you may not use anything: % ($Obj in $Array) {Get-msolUser -UserPrincipalName $Obj.UserPrincipalName -ReturnDeletedUsers |...

Comment: It should probably be noted that most Microsoft examples of `-Filter`s use single quotes as the outer quotes and double quotes as the inner quotes, so `Get-ADUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -eq "$foo"' ...` (or, in this case, `... -eq "$($obj.UserPrincipalName)"'`. I suspect that there is a reason for this.

Comment: Jeff, i tried before posting:Get-AdUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -eq "$Obj.UserPrincipalName"' -Server $Domain, even tried the other way arround: Get-AdUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$Obj.UserPrincipalName'" -Server $Domain. And also tried Get-AdUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq "$($Obj.UserPrincipalName)"} -Server $Domain, which also failed.